# How to achieve operator overloading in java and C#?

Tags: c#, java, polymorphism, operator-overloading

I know there is no such thing like Operator Overloading in Java and C#. A task is given to me by my teacher to achieve operator overloading in any of these languages. I don't know the deep concepts of these languages, only basic OOP. So can any one tell is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried to google *"operator overloading in java and C#?"* This is the second link. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228498(v=vs.90).aspx.

Answer (score 6):

There is a thing called *operator overloading* in C#, check out this code snippet from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

```
public struct Complex 
{
   public int real;
   public int imaginary;

   public Complex(int real, int imaginary) 
   {
      this.real = real;
      this.imaginary = imaginary;
   }

   // Declare which operator to overload (+), the types 
   // that can be added (two Complex objects), and the 
   // return type (Complex):
   public static Complex operator +(Complex c1, Complex c2) 
   {
      return new Complex(c1.real + c2.real, c1.imaginary + c2.imaginary);
   }
}
```

[Full list of overloadable operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s.aspx)

Comment: great..I didn't know that. That I noted for C#. And If you can give me some similar type of solution in java also, I will mark your answer. thank you

Comment: I'm not a Java expert, but as far as I know, there is no operator overloading in it.

Comment: Ok I will wait for other answers than if I am not satisfied with others, I will mark yours for sure..

Comment: Also make sure that you really need operator overloading, maybe all you need is to create some thing like `Add`, `Remove` methods

Comment: No the question asked to me by my teacher is straight forward that achieve operator overloading in these two langs. No other information given.

Answer (score 0):

As des has shown, C# does have operator overloading. Java, on the other hand, does not. The way Java compares that two objects are equal is done through overriding the method `equals(Object)`, which is inherited from the base object `java.lang.Object`. Here's an example usage:

```
public class MyClass {
    private int value;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return o instanceof MyClass && ((MyClass)o).value == this.value;
    }
}
```

Of course this is only a workaround for replicating overloading the `==` operator. For other operators, such as `>=` or `<=` there is nothing. However, you can use OO to *sort of* recreate it by using a common interface:

```
interface Overloadable<T> {
    public boolean isGreaterThan(T other);
    public boolean isLessThan(T other);
}

public class MyClass implements Overloadable<MyClass> {
    private int value;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return o instanceof MyClass && ((MyClass)o).value == this.value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isGreaterThan(MyClass other) {
        return this.value > other.value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLessThan(MyClass other) {
        return this.value < other.value;
    }
}
```

This is by no means real operator overloading because, well, you're not overloading the operators. It does however provide the ability to compare objects in the same way.